Как изменить цвет панели управления окном JavaFX
Возможно ли изменить цвет стандартной панели управления окном Windows на JavaFX
Буду благодарен за ответ

Вы можете использовать WinAPI для изменения цвета заголовка окна.
В Windows 10 его можно сделать черного цвета через DwmSetWindowAttribute с помощью атрибута DWMWA_USE_IMMERSIVE_DARK_MODE(20)
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/dwmapi/ne-dwmapi-dwmwindowattribute
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/dwmapi/nf-dwmapi-dwmsetwindowattribute
Пример использования этой функции на java 21 (аргументы jvm для запуска --enable-preview --enable-native-access=ALL-UNNAMED) с javafx 23:
import com.sun.javafx.tk.TKStage;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.lang.foreign.Arena;
import java.lang.foreign.FunctionDescriptor;
import java.lang.foreign.Linker;
import java.lang.foreign.SymbolLookup;
import java.lang.invoke.MethodHandle;

import static java.lang.foreign.ValueLayout.*;

public class App extends Application {
    void run() {
        launch();
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        stage.setScene(new Scene(new Pane()));
        
        useImmersiveDarkMode(stage);
    }

    void useImmersiveDarkMode(Stage stage) {
        final int DWMWA_USE_IMMERSIVE_DARK_MODE = 20;

        Arena arena = Arena.ofConfined();
        Linker linker = Linker.nativeLinker();
        MethodHandle dwmSetWindowAttribute = linker.downcallHandle(
                SymbolLookup
                        .libraryLookup("Dwmapi", arena)
                        .find("DwmSetWindowAttribute")
                        .orElseThrow(),
                FunctionDescriptor.of(JAVA_LONG, JAVA_LONG, JAVA_INT, ADDRESS, JAVA_INT));

        stage.setWidth(499);
        stage.setHeight(499);
        stage.show();

        try {
            // Получение дескриптора окна
            var getPeer = stage.getClass().getSuperclass().getDeclaredMethod("getPeer");
            getPeer.setAccessible(true);
            var hwnd = ((TKStage) getPeer.invoke(stage)).getRawHandle();

            dwmSetWindowAttribute.invoke(
                    hwnd,
                    DWMWA_USE_IMMERSIVE_DARK_MODE,
                    arena.allocate(JAVA_INT, 1),
                    4
            );
        } catch (Throwable _) {
        }

        arena.close();

        //обновления размеров окна чтобы изменения стали видимыми
        stage.setWidth(500);
        stage.setHeight(500);
    }
}


void main() {
    new App().run();
}

на более старых версиях foreign functions api может отличаться или можно вызвать DwmSetWindowAttribute через JNI:
native void useImmersiveDarkMode(long hwnd, boolean value);
#include <jni.h>
#include "Dwmapi.h"

JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_App_useImmersiveDarkMode(JNIEnv* env, jobject obj, jlong hwnd, jint value) {
    DwmSetWindowAttribute((HWND)hwnd, DWMWA_USE_IMMERSIVE_DARK_MODE, &value, sizeof(int));
}

Команда компиляции через clang:
clang -shared -I"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-21\include" -I"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-21\include\win32" -lDwmapi -o lib.dll lib.c
import com.sun.javafx.tk.TKStage;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.io.File;

public class App extends Application {
    void run() {
        System.load(new File("./lib.dll").getAbsolutePath());
        launch();
    }

    native void useImmersiveDarkMode(long hwnd, boolean value);

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        stage.setScene(new Scene(new Pane()));

        stage.setWidth(499);
        stage.setHeight(499);
        stage.show();

        var getPeer = stage.getClass().getSuperclass().getDeclaredMethod("getPeer");
        getPeer.setAccessible(true);
        var hwnd = ((TKStage) getPeer.invoke(stage)).getRawHandle();

        useImmersiveDarkMode(hwnd, true);

        stage.setWidth(500);
        stage.setHeight(500);
    }
}

В Windows 11 добавили возможность установить любой цвет для фона и цвет шрифта заголовка через атрибуты
DWMWA_BORDER_COLOR(34)
DWMWA_CAPTION_COLOR(35)
DWMWA_TEXT_COLOR(36)

Спасибо за ответ. Но можно узнать, как можно изменить цвет этой панели, без использования java.lang.foreign.Arena? (у меня не получается импортировать её, хотя я указал все необходимые опции JVM, и изменил jdk на 21)

я добавил пример с использованием JNI вместо foreign functions

спасибо за ответ
